# Page builder in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, page-builder

We are going to build a magento2 website which is already in magento1, and having 300+ CMS Pages and some of CMS Blogs.

For that i'm looking for the theme which supports the page builder extension.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is two way

1. Claue Theme You can purchase link - [Click Here](http://themes.magesolution.com/claue/m2/)

   - I am also using this theme, this have free Page builder. Purchase Link - [Click Here](https://themeforest.net/item/claue-clean-minimal-magento-2-theme/20155150). Also this theme package contains both Magento1 and Magento2.
   - Demo of Page Builder - [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPfHHv0spJc)
2. Another This you can use any of the theme and Purchase Magento 2 Page Builder

   - Coder Vendor is Providing Page Builder Extension. Check: [Click Here](https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-page-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you for help !

Comment: It's our pleasure!